# ffmpegでmp4から静止画が作れない

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

CentOS7.2でstaticのffmpegを使ってmp4ファイルから静止画(jpg)を作ろうとしています。
以前はyumでインストールしたffmpegを使ってできていた記憶はあるものの（たしか・・・）、エラーが出て作れなくなりstaticのffmpegを持ってきました。しかし、同様の事象です。
高速で作りたいので「-ss」を前に持ってきています。以下、実行のログとエラーの内容です。対処方法をご存知の方はご教示お願いします。

```
$ ./ffmpeg -ss 200 -i /mnt/ram/enc/fb9f7f36627a684271c2b7154b6b3f10.mp4 -vframes 1 -f image2 -s 320x180 /mnt/ram/enc/fb9f7f36627a684271c2b7154b6b3f10.jpg
ffmpeg version N-82240-g55061bb-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-3) 20161019
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libebur128 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 66.101 / 57. 66.101
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/ram/enc/fb9f7f36627a684271c2b7154b6b3f10.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.55.100
  Duration: 00:48:46.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 130 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, image2, to '/mnt/ram/enc/fb9f7f36627a684271c2b7154b6b3f10.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: ログを見る限り、その mp4 データには音声データ(mp4a フォーマット)しか入っていない様に見えますが、、

Comment: なるほど。本当ですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ログを見る限り、対象の mp4 ファイルには音声データ (mp4a フォーマット) しか入っていないのが原因だと思われます。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/30121/ffmpeg%e3%81%a7mp4%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e9%9d%99%e6%ad%a2%e7%94%bb%e3%81%8c%e4%bd%9c%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment29182_30121) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*